# How to create a trapezium shape using svg?

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

I wish to draw an upside-down spotlight for my web page. I would add some helpful code here but there isn't any and I have exhausted the entirety of internet to find anything helpful. I'm still learning HTML and CSS, so any suggestion in these areas would be nice. Also, I understand that a common way of creating a trapezium is using 'border-bottom/left/right' property but the problem there is that I can't fill the shape that forms with a gradient. So, any assistance on how to create a trapezium like this: `\_/` would be quite helpful.

Comment: Hi Jacob, welcome to stack overflow and web development in general. It is more appropriate to share whatever you have tried and more importantly to first try spending some time in figuring out the solution. It's a suggestion I can give you to boost your performance while learning to code.  By the way I assume you can use clip path in this case to create the desired shape. [Try out this generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: For SVG - Try http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html

Comment: @RifkyNiyas Thank you for the kind welcome. I understand your point and I truly would have posted a helpful code if there was one left. I tried using several methods and none of them worked and it got really frustrating, so I ended up deleting all of it. But I will keep your suggestion in mind for the next times. Thanks for the link, it's nice to experiment. Have a good day ahead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to create a trapezium without an svg is to use CSS clip-path with the path being defined as a polygon. The points of the polygon can be set as % values so the element can be made responsive.

This CSS

```
.trapezium {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow, blue, green);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 20% 100%);
}
```

gives this:

[image]

```css
.trapezium {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow, blue, green);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 20% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezium"></div>
```

You can use a similar technique if it has to be an SVG rather than achieved through plain CSS/HTML. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon which describes how to use a polygon as an SVG path.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much!! That worked, and it's definitely easier than SVG. You're a total godsend! Thanks again and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that SVG is easier. But judge for yourself. Here is the equivalent SVG to the div/CSS version.

```css
.trapezium {
  width: 30vmin;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 20" class="trapezium">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="orange"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellow"/>
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="blue"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <polygon points="0,0, 30,0, 24,20, 6,20" fill="url(#grad)"/>
</svg>
```